# How to determine if $z(x,y)=\ln(x^2 + y^2)$ is a harmonic function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform, multivalued-functions

So I know that a function is harmonic if it satisfies Laplace's equation:

$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$

But I'm just not sure how I should put it in to action for a practice question I have, which is:
Determine if $z(x,y) = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$ is a harmonic function.

Comment: You compute $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2z}{dy^2}$ and check if it's zero. If it is then the function is harmonic, if it's not then it's not.

Comment: What is $z_{xx}$? $z_{yy}$? If you can compute these, then just sum them and show it is $0$ or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chain Rule, $\partial z/\partial x=2x/(x^2+y^2)$. Now by the quotient rule, $$\partial^2 z/\partial x^2=\frac{2(x^2+y^2)-2x(2x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{2(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Similarly $\partial^2 z/\partial y^2=\frac{2(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. But this is the negative of the previous answer, so they add to zero.

Comment: You need to be a bit careful about the point $x=y=0$ as the derivatives do not exist there. The function is only harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $(0,0)$.

Comment: I had assumed the asker was already working on this domain, as their function is also not defined there...

Answer (score -1):

Any real function $u(x,y)$ with continuous second partial derivatives which satisfies Laplace's equation,

$$\nabla ^2u(x,y)=0$$is called a harmonic function.

$z(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$
$$\nabla ^2 z(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}$$
 you can solve the above expression and it must equal to $0$ to be satisfied for  the harmonic function